# Nonlinear ODE to linear PDE?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, classical-mechanics, schrodinger-operators, quantization

I am interested in when and how one can trade a non-liner ODE for a linear PDE. To explain what this could look like here is a physics-inspired discussion.

Consider a classical mechanical system with one degree on freedom $q$ and a Hamiltonian $H(q,p,t)$. The equations of motion can be cast as the Euler-Lagrange equations which are second-order ODE, non-linear in the generic case. Yet another equivalent way is through the Hamilton-Jacobi equation
$$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+H\left(q,\frac{\partial S}{\partial q},t\right)=0 \qquad (1)$$
which is a single non-linear PDE.

Quantum-mechanically this system is described by a linear Schrodinger equation (I gloss over all ambiguities and subtleties that might be in quantizing a classical system)
$$-i\hbar\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}+H(q,-i\hbar\partial_q,t)\psi=0 \qquad (2)$$

Formally, equation (1) is the $\hbar\to0$ limit of equation (2) if one makes the following ansatz $\psi=e^{iS/\hbar}$. So it seems that at least formally for a large class of ODE one can find an equivalent linear PDE. I am interested to learn if there is any systematic theory to back up this heuristic arguments.

Comment: I think you are playing a bit loose with the term "equivalent". As you point out yourself, the $\hbar\to 0$ limit is necessary to relate solutions of the Schroedinger and Hamilton-Jacobi equations. Moreover, the HJ equation is an ODE only in the stationary case with one spatial dimension. I think your question could do with some clarification.

Comment: Any ODE system trivially corresponds to a linear hyperbolic PDE for which the ODE solution curves are characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

[When Nonlinear Differential Equations are Equivalent to Linear Differential Equations](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~bluman/SIAM1982.pdf)

> A necessary and sufficient condition is established for the existence
> of a 1-1 transformation of a system of nonlinear differential
> equations to a system of linear equations. The obtained theorems
> enable one to construct such transformations from the invariance
> groups of differential equations. The hodograph transformation, the
> Legendre transformation and Lie’s transformation of the Monge-Ampère
> equation are shown to be special cases. Noninvertible transformations
> are also considered. Examples include Burgers’ equation, a nonlinear
> diffusion equation and the Liouville equation.

I don't think the Schrödinger equation is a useful example in this class, because the correspondence between the classical and quantum dynamics breaks down after a time $T$ that grows only logarithmically when $\hbar$ is sent to zero.$^\ast$ So you will not be able to follow the classical dynamics for a meaningful time even if $\hbar$ is very small. One way in which this difficulty appears, is that the classical dynamics can be chaotic, whereas quantum dynamics is quasiperiodic.

$^\ast$ The time $T$ at which the quantum-classical correspondence breaks down is called the [Ehrenfest time](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ehrenfest_time_and_chaos), it is of the order $T=\alpha^{-1}\log\hbar$, with $\alpha$ the Lyapunov exponent of the classical dynamics.

Comment: Thanks for both links, very instructive. However I had something a bit different in mind, perhaps not articulated clearly. As far as I can tell the paper that you linked mostly considers 1-1 mappings of between linear and non-linear diff equations (with some reservations for not 1-1 mappings.) The mappings exists only for very particular types of equations. In contrast I was asking if one can trade non-linearity for linearity in a possibly much larger space. In my example $q(t)$ is a one-parameter function with a non-linear equation while $\psi(q,t)$ is now two-parameter but obeying the linear